# Триггеры и разные кодировки

Tags: триггер, кодировка, перекодировка, mysql

Ситуация: в случае изменений в *таблице1* триггер пишет в *таблицу2* некое сообщение на русском языке. Кодировка этих таблиц:

```
cp1251_general_ci
```

А вот в таблице *TRIGGERS* базы данных *information_schema* кодировка - **UTF8**.

Как итог - в *таблицу2* пишутся крокозябры. Как меньшей кровью исправить ситуацию, чтобы писались читаемые данные?

Comment: @Виталина ♦, объясните, пожалйуста, смысл правки заголовка.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

может подойдет таблица с сообщениями из которой их брать триггером ?

Comment: Классный вариант. Так и сделал.